# R: Customize a character class

Tags: regex, r, class, character, subset

Say I want to create a character class for all the letters in the top row of the keyboard. I know I can express them as `[qwertyuiop]`, but I don't want to have to type that every time.

Is there a way to customize a character class for them and call it `'top'`, so that when I need to look for all instances of "papa", "tata" or "yaya" in my data.
Then I can just type something like `"[:top:]a[:top:]a"`.

Any other simple solutions are also welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't define your own character class `…`

Although, you could consider the few possibilities I have came up with.

1. You could define the character class inside of a [**Named Capturing Group**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#namedgroups), and then backreference the named group in your pattern along the way.

   ```
   x <- 'papa tata yaya foo bar'
   gsub('(?<top>[qwertyuiop])a\\k<top>a', '', x, perl=T)
   # [1] "   foo bar"
   ```
2. You could shorten this by recalling the group `(?1)` itself, although it's not named.

   ```
   gsub('([qwertyuiop])a(?1)a', '', x, perl=T)
   ```
3. You could utilize `sprintf`, but you would have to continually write out the values.

   ```
   top <- '[qwertyuiop]'
   gsub(sprintf('%sa%sa', top, top), '', x)
   ```

But overall, you can't create your own custom named character class.

Comment: Regex ninja strikes again

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! A follow-up question: whether I call the class `<top>` or `(?1)`, if I define it once at the beginning of my script (i.e. `<top>` = `[qwertyuiop]`), am I allowed to refer to it by that name outside of that line of command and for the rest of the script? If so, what is a simple command to define `<top>` as `[qwertyuiop]`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using hwnd's excellent answer you could also store that strategy in a function:

```
> gsubtop <- function(pattern, replacement, x) gsub(paste0('(?<top>[qwertyuiop])', pattern), replacement, x, perl=T)
> x <- 'papa tata yaya foo bar'
> gsubtop('a\\k<top>a', '', x)
[1] "   foo bar"
```